# ClickOnce Microsoft.Data.Services.Client referencing wrong version

Tags: c#, clickonce

In my project I have updated my references to Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.3.0.0.
However when I deploy with clickonce it still trys to reference: 
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.0.0.0 and throws the error Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.0.0.0 needs to be installed to the GAC.
[image: Error]

The 5.3.0.0 dll's are being included with the clickonce install.
I can't go back to 5.0.0.0 cause the Service Reference has 5.3.0.0 features.

Is there a way I can manually tell clickonce to use 5.3.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the bind [**bindingRedirect**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/eftw1fys.aspx) tag in your config file.

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.3.0.0"/>
```

Also you need to make sure that the new *Microsoft.Data.Services.Client 5.3.0.0* assembly is present in GAC.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me but I also found the problem. I had 2 WCF apps and a C# client application. When the client referenced the first WCF application which was version 5.3.0.0 it picked up the dependancy from the WCF app that the first WCF app was referencing. Therefore the final solution I used was updating the second WCF app to version 5.3.0.0 :) Thanks for the help